# Ayuda con esta tarea sobre funciones

Tags: python, funciones, números-primos

Reincido en consulta sobre esta tarea que me piden en una formación online. Deciros que no tenemos soporte de profesores y como estudiantes estamos a la deriva. mas bien en plan autodidacta. Dicho esto deciros que mis dudas son:

1. el compilador web del sitio no me permitía hacer un input de dato cuando quería que el usuario ingresase un número; con lo que debo buscar la manera que la función trabaje sobre un número no dado pero que tiene que hacer cálculos sobre el mismo. Por lo que no sé como programar la variable sin ingresarla como parámetro. Evidentemente me dice que la variable no está definida.
2. Debo consultar sobre ese número dos cosas: si es pandigital y si es primo, nos piden que sea con una función, no supe hacerlo sino haciendo funciones dentro de función pero estoy hecha un ocho con los retornos y usar éstos para hacer las comprobaciones con If y else para que me de la información de si es o no.
3. También con las llamadas a función O_o

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

## El código que llevo hecho:

```
def es_panprimo ():

      def es_pandigital ():

          global num_inicial
          digitos = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

          pandigital = True
          for digito in digitos:
              if digito not in num_inicial:
                 pandigital = False

          return pandigital

      def es_primo ():

          global num_inicial
          ultimos_digitos = int(num_inicial[-3:])

          resultado = True
          for i in range(2,ultimos_digitos):

             if ultimos_digitos%i==0:

                resultado = False

          return resultado

      es_pandigital()
      es_primo()
      return      



es_panprimo ()


if pandigital == True and resultado == True:
      print("True", "El número ingresado es panprimo")
elif pandigital == True and resultado == False:
      print("False", "El número ingresado es pandigital pero no es primo")
elif pandigital == False and resultado == True:
      print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital pero es primo")
else:
      print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital ni primo")
```

`

Comment: Has probado a hacer global num_inicial fuera de la función? (lo mismo es una obviedad lo que digo, pero no lo veo en tu código)

Comment: Hola @JoseManuelMorales, ahora mismo no está incorporado pero antes cuando solicitaba al usuario mediante num_inicial = input ("") tenía más sentido lo de global num_inicial dentro de las funciones...ahora se me hace hasta raro verlo allí porque dónde-antes se ha declarado esa variable?!. O tu te refieres a simplemente a poner en el programa principal esa declaración sin más...

Comment: Estás operando con num_inicial, pero no está declarada en ningún lado. Si te piden que operes sin que el usuario meta input deberás declarar en la función es_panprimo () esa variable y asignarle un valor numérico. De lo contrario te dirá que num_inicial no existe y, por tanto, no se puede hacer global.

Comment: Ojo, que lo que te digo es sin saber python, solo aplico la lógica de las funciones de jquery y PHP. Si algo no existe y operas con ello te dice que no existe.

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales correcto. voy a tener que hacer algo así porque al fin y al cabo es un ejercicio y me objetivo es seguir con la formación pero aún me queda la duda de cómo deberia ser sin meterle valor desde el principio es decir siendo el usuario quien ingrese el valor de la variable. Gracias José por tu ayuda.

Comment: ^^ De nada. No es una solución, por lo que deberías esperar que alguien te diga algo mas, pero algo es algo.

Comment: ¿Número inicial que se supone que contiene? Un string, un int, float.. Por tu código supongo que un string, pero es para cerciorarme.

Answer (score 1):

El programa que te mostraré a continuación consta de 3 funciones; main(n), pandigital(n) y primo(n). Las funciones pandigital() y primo() retornan un valor booleano (quiero dejar claro que cada una retorna un valor booleano de acuerdo al valor que le pases como parámetro). En el caso de pandigital(), retornará True si el valor que le pases como parámetro es un número pandigital y retornará False en caso contrario. La función primo(), retornará True si el valor que le pases como parámetro es un número primo y retornará False en caso contrario. Ahora, yo usé la función main() para mandar a llamar a las otras dos funciones (pandigital() y primo()) y para imprimir un mensaje que me indique si el valor que le pasé como parámetro al main() es pandigital y primo.

```
def main(n):
    if (pandigital(n) & primo(n)):
        print('El numero %s es pandigital y primo.' % (n))

def pandigital(x):
    nums = list(range(1,len(str(x))+1))
    nums = ''.join(str(n) for n in nums)
    for v in nums:
        if v not in str(x):
            return False
    return True

def primo(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

main(2143)
```

**Tratando de aclarar tus puntos**

*1.* Por lo que entiendo con ese punto es que el valor que se va a buscar es un valor que no ingresa el usuario, por lo tanto es a criterio del programador y por ende, a mi parecer, las soluciones son muchas:

- Iterar a través de un rango de valores que va hasta *n* para
  encontrar todos los números que son primos y pandigitales en ese
  rango.
- Definir una variable de forma arbitraria y pasarla como parámetro al main() como yo lo hice.
- Usar argumentos de la línea de comando.

Como podrás ver, ahí habría que ser más específico en cuanto a la solución esperada para tu problema en particular.

*2.* No hay mucho más en lo que podría elaborar en cuanto a este punto creo yo, ya todo lo definí en el primer párrafo.

*3.* Un ejemplo de mandar a llamar una función es como lo que hice en la última línea de código. Supuse que debía aclarar eso por el gesto (O_o).

Answer (score 0):

**Primer Punto**

No se si es una obligación, o no, por parte de del curso online que estás haciendo, el usar un "compilador web", pero te sugiero que hagas los desarrollos en un ide, como "Sublime", "PyCharm", "Atom", etc.. o al menos en el interprete de python (Con el comando `python` en una consola o terminal, es suficiente, a mi me gusta `ipython` que lo instalas a través de `pip` con el comando `pip install ipython`)

Una vez dicho esto, he reproducido tu código para que funcione, de la mejor manera que he sabido. En el poco tiempo que llevo desarrollando en python nunca he visto funciones que contengan funciones, salvo en casos muy específicos, a través de funciones lambda o de decoradores. Para alguien que está aprendiendo a programar se me antoja confuso.

Se que lo has hecho por la problemática del "compilador web" que estás utilizando, por eso te recomiendo que utilices un ide y desarrolles en ámbitos locales, luego ya podrás subir tu código y modificar lo que sea necesario para que se adapte al "compilador web".

**Segundo Punto**

Aquí he estructurado tu código, el cual no estaba demasiado desencaminado, para que funcione como se supone que debe hacerlo, seguro que el código se puede refactorizar, pero he preferido dejarlo así para que lo entiendas más fácilmente (creo que ya lo entiendes, pero por si acaso lo ve alguien que venga después de nosotros). Así que esto es lo que hecho, y a mi me funciona.

```
def es_pandigital(numero):

    digitos = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    pandigital = True
    for digito in digitos:
        if digito not in numero:
           pandigital = False

    return pandigital

def es_primo(numero):

    ultimos_digitos = int(numero[-3:])

    resultado = True
    for i in range(2,ultimos_digitos):

       if ultimos_digitos%i==0:

          resultado = False

    return resultado  


try:
  numero = str(input('Introduzca un número por favor: '))
except Exception:
  print Exception.message

pandigital = es_pandigital(numero)
resultado = es_primo(numero)

if pandigital and resultado:
      print("True", "El número ingresado es panprimo")

elif pandigital and not resultado:
      print("False", "El número ingresado es pandigital pero no es primo")

elif resultado and not pandigital:
      print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital pero es primo")

else:
      print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital ni primo")
```

Para correr este script a través de una consola:

`python 'url_al_archivo.py'`

**Salida sobre el código generado**

[image: Imagen de salida del código generado]

Luego el paso por los condicionales los puedes dejar como los he puesto o encapsularlos en otra función, algo así:

```
def comprobar_resultado(pandigital, resultado):
    if pandigital and resultado:
        print("True", "El número ingresado es panprimo")
    elif pandigital and not resultado:
        print("False", "El número ingresado es pandigital pero no es primo")
    elif resultado and not pandigital:
        print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital pero es primo")
    else:
        print("False","El número ingresado no es pandigital ni primo")
```

Donde el resultado sería este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo!!

**P.D.**

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que mi código está hecho en python2.7 y el tuyo es python3, aunque no debería fallar.